# find internal functions in R

Tags: r, quantmod

While reading the help file of `getSymbols {quantmod}`, I came across following lines:

The “sourcing” of data is managed internally through a complex lookup procedure. If symbol.lookup is TRUE (the default), a check is made if any symbol has had its source specified by setSymbolLookup.

I was wondering whether it is possible to view this complex lookup procedure (or internal functions).

Comment: Related: [How can I view the source code for a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19226816/271616)

Comment: @Joshua: Thanks. I can view the source code for this function, but how about the lines that I mentioned in the OP. Are these two the same?

Comment: The `quantmod` packages is available on [github](https://github.com/R-Finance/quantmod) and the functions that are included are in the usual location within the `/R` sub-directory, including [getSymbols](https://github.com/R-Finance/quantmod/blob/master/R/getSymbols.R).